# How to set a minimum width with background-size

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is 1000px X 600px .  I want to use it as a responsive background for a div but would like to set a minimum width of 1000px despite how small the browser window is.

This is frustrating because there doesn't seem to be a simple way to define a min. width.

If I use background-size: cover  - for some reason, the image is defaulted much larger than 1000px.

please help

Comment: have to tried defining a min width on a parent element that has your image as the background? then the rest of your content can go inside that.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The "background-size: cover" seems to use the height of the <body> tag to determine the width of the image.  This is soooo stupid.  Why doesn't it use the set height of the div?

Comment: You mean *max*-width not *min*-width, correct?! Orherwise your last sentence makes no sense: *the image is defaulted much larger than 1000px.*

Comment: no, I want a min width of 1000 px for the image.  It can be as large as it wants as long as the browser window is greater than 1000px

Comment: have you got some html to post? is your background sizing on the body?

Answer (score 20):

If media queries are an option, you can setup a media query for browser viewports smaller than 1000px wide.

Assuming your HTML viewport is set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

And your div is named 'bg':

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

In your CSS:

```
.bg {
    width: auto; /* Scale the div to the parent width */
    height: 900px; /* The div needs some height to be visible */
    background-image: url(bg.png); /* This is your background image */
    background-size: 100%; /* Always size the image to the width of the div */
    background-position: top; /* Position the image to the top center of the div */
}

/* For any viewports less than 1000px wide */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {

    .bg {
        background-size: 1000px 600px; /* Force the image to its minimum width */
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a note, don't forger to use _prefixes_. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: I'd rather user `background-size: initial` within the media query one. :D

Answer (score 8):

There's now an option for `background-size` to *only* scale the image until the picture has met it actual height/width. This way, you don't have to set a min-width or anything.

In your CSS:

```
body {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values

Comment: `background-size: cover` won't stop shrinking at the actual size of the image

Answer (score 5):

You can use `calc` in `background-size`:

```
.bg {
    background-size: calc(max(100%, 1000px));
}
```

`calc` works also with `background-position`, for one side, or both sides

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The following code worked for me. I just had to add a min width in the same element. Here I just used the html element, I would assume that it would be more conventional to use the body element

```
     /* CSS Style Sheet */

 html    { background-image:url(example.JPG);
                    background-size:cover;
                    min-width:1000px;}
```

I hope this helps,