# Defining a minimum width to background image

Tags: html, css, width, background-image, minimum

I'm trying to make a backround image in my webpage, defining the size to 80%. That works. I want to make my background image "responsive", so I want it to resize when using smaller windows. It does resize, but ofcourse it's to small to see it perfectly. Is there a way to define a minimum-width to the image?
Thanks!

Here's my CSS:

```
.pageBio{height: 700px; background-image: url(https://****.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-color: #2a67b2; background-size:80%; text-align: center; font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; color: black;
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: There is one attribute called `min-width`

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679221/how-to-set-a-minimum-width-with-background-size can help (media queries).

Answer (score 2):

As you already saying that you are making image responsive. so you can define image size on by using media query mentioned below..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){.pageBio{background-size:cover;}}
```

or

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px){.pageBio{background-size:auto 100%; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

friend try this code :
background-size:80%; replace below code and check it

```
background-size:150px 150px;
```