# How can I apply min-width on div background?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="background: url(http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/11/picjumbo.com_IMG_3130.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%; min-width: 700px; height: 100%; width: auto;">

  <p>
    I DO NOT WANT THIS CONTENT TO BE AFFECTED BY THE MIN-WIDTH. I just want the background to take on min-width. I hope that makes sense.</p>

</div>
```

Here is my Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/y0bdLgzL/2/

- I am applying the styling in-line because for this particular project I need to be able to dynamically generate the background image based on a database.
- I am trying to get the background to take on a min-width property, but not the content/text.

Any help on how to properly arrange divs and classes to help make this happen would be very helpful.

Comment: What is your aim, always to have full width? I don't think there is a clean way to set a min-width to a background-image due to it's a part of the element. One way: Using :before with position:absolute to have more control or something of these tricks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679221/how-to-set-a-minimum-width-with-background-size

Comment: Right, to have its width always be covered until a certain point and then it won't scale anymore. Problem is, the text that is over top of the image scales with it. I don't want that. :(

Comment: See my proposal above. But the easiest way would be to add a child element for the text width a max-width.

Comment: Posted a working sample for you, using a pseudo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't give a background image a min-width, you could use a pseudo element, like this.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0bdLgzL/3/)

```css
.bkg {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.bkg::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/11/picjumbo.com_IMG_3130.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
}
.bkg p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <div class="bkg">

    <p>
      I DO NOT WANT THIS CONTENT TO BE AFFECTED BY THE MIN-WIDTH. I just want the background to take on min-width, not the content. I hope that makes sense.</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: For whatever reason, it works just fine fiddle, but I can literally copy and paste it into an html/css file and the background doesnt appear at all.

Comment: @BrianBreeden Then post that html/css code and I'll have a look

Comment: This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zhLcskuo/   This is really frustrating. My local files are, literally (with the addition of <html>, etc exactly the same. I can change the image all day but it doesn't appear. >=(

Comment: @BrianBreeden But that one work?? ... what does your html/css look like that does **not** work?

Comment: That is the head scratcher. This is what I am looking at, complete with output outside of fiddle in a html/css file: http://imgur.com/a/KC81I

Comment: @BrianBreeden Ahh ... the reason why the image does not show is because your image path is wrong. The path given in the CSS use the CSS's path as root, so your image path should likely be `../images/tst-photo.jpg`

Comment: OH I AM AN IDIOT. Thank you for your patience. I am still learning the basics with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this result by using the `::before` pseudo element, something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum solor dit amet
    </p>
</div>

.wrapper { height: 100%; position: relative; width: auto; }
.wrapper::before { background: url('img/bg.png') 0 0/100% 100% cover; content: ''; min-width: 700px; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

Size the `.wrapper::before` and the background will follow!

Comment: I was about to delete my answer when I saw you posted one while I wrote mine up, but since your does not work properly, I'll leave mine as is.

Comment: Do I need to answer that?? ... Make a sample snippet or a fiddle and check for yourself

Comment: lol :p take it easy rider! if you're refering to a non-existing image, yeah, sure, it doesn't work. But otherwise it looks legit to me. I guess our friend is smart enough to insert his own pic there ;) and besides, it's a q&a site, not a ready-made-script-generator. That's why I said, _something like this_, instead of _exactly like this_

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment came out harsh :) ... but what's the point to post a code sample that _almost_ work? ... and it is not only a non existing image we talk about